# creating and manipulating 3d arrays

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

I am (very) new to python, previously a Matlab user.

I try to create code to load times series into the rows of a matrix [serie1, 2, 3, etc.] and then manipulate those time series into a loop (see code below).
My problem is threefold (3 loops below):

1-how to create a loop to fill the array's rows one by one.
2-fill a 3d array of with stuff I calculate off those time series (correlation coefficients)
3-calculate the average correlation of the lower triangular matrix for each time period

what i am doing wrong?

thanks a lot for your help!

```
i=0   
while i<length(fx_tech):
    for f in fx_tech:
        time_series[:,i]= (LoadSeries(f[2],'7','fx','0',(ts.now('Y')-20).asfreq('B'),ts.now('B')-1,'0','0','B'))
    i=1+i


    #i want to populate a matrix with all series, fx_tech is a list of series i have 
    #to feed through the "loadseries" command. I know the first set of loops is wrong.
#then loop over each series pair and populate the matrix "corr"

corr = zeros((len(time_series)-1,len(fx_tech),len(fx_tech)))  #allocate matrix

i=0
j=0
while i < len(fx_tech):
    while j < len(fx_tech):
        corr[:,i,j] = gencorrelation(time_series[:,i],time_series[:,j],lambda1)
        j=1+j
    i=1+i 

#finally calculate the average of the elements below the diagonal for each time period.

mean_fx = []
i=0
while i < len(time_series)-1:
    diag[:,:] = corr[i,:,:]-eye(len(fx_tech))
    mean_fx.append = sum(diag)/((len(fx_tech)**2)/2-len(fx_tech))
    i=1+i
```

Comment: For people to better answer your question you might want to add some sample output as well as a sample of what output you expect to see.